# Prevent one snap from starting if a mount partition is unavailable

Tags: mount, snap, nextcloud

I have a snap container that should never be running when a disk is not properly mounted.  How could I prevent to start the snap when the disk is not there ?

My usecase is a nextcloud snap with external storage on a mounted disk.
If the next cloud snap starts without the disk mounted, nextcloud believe that it has been deleted... which trigger a crazy data synchronization with a big risk of data loss.

Thanks in advance,
Loic

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed on your Nextcloud (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.